# Print statement not responding in my filemanagement system

Tags: python, file-management

I have 2 folders: Source and Destination. Each of those folders have 3 subfolders inside them named A, B and C. The 3 subfolders in Source all contain multiple files. The 3 subfolders in Destination are empty (yet).

I need the full path of all because my goal is to overwrite the files from Source A, B and C  in Destination A, B and C.

How come my two print statements are not printing anything? I have zero errors.

```
import os

src = r'c:\data\AM\Desktop\Source'
dst = r'c:\data\AM\Desktop\Destination'     

os.chdir(src)                             

for root, subdirs, files in os.walk(src):
    for f in subdirs:
        subdir_paths = os.path.join(src, f)
        subdir_paths1 = os.path.join(dst, f)

        for a in files:
            file_paths = os.path.join(subdir_paths, a) 
            file_paths1 = os.path.join(subdir_paths1, a)
            print(file_paths)
            print(file_paths1)
```

Comment: If nothing is being printed, the collections you're iterating over must be empty. Double check your data.

Comment: No, my subfolders in Source contain multiple textfiles...

Comment: Double check you paths then. The now-deleted answer showed that `files` is always empty.

Comment: You are misunderstanding how `os.walk()` works.  The files returned in `files` are in the `root` directory; you are acting as if though they existed in each of the `subdirs` directories, which are actually in `root` themselves.

Comment: If either `subdirs` or `files` are empty, the loop `for a in files` won't be entered.

Comment: @Carcigenicate  Believe it nor not, there is nothing wrong with my paths. Its very simple... my src path has 3 subfolder (A, B and C) all this 3 subfolders contain multiple files. My dst path also has 3 subfolders (A, B, and C) these are all empty.

Comment: @jasonharper So what is the solution?

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. At the moment you're missing input (files in `src`) and expected output. `dst` doesn't seem relevant to the problem, so you could probably just remove it and everything that follows from it.

Comment: The solution is to *not do anything with `subdirs`*, when they are entirely irrelevant to what you're doing.  (`os.walk()` will recurse into them on its own.)

Comment: @jasonharper so you are saying just using for f in files: os.path.join(root, f)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem

As [jasonharper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1709364/jasonharper) said in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62283373/print-statement-not-responding-in-my-filemanagement-system#comment110153567_62283373),

> You are misunderstanding how `os.walk()` works. The files returned in `files` are in the `root` directory; you are acting as if though they existed in each of the `subdirs` directories, which are actually in `root` themselves.

The reason nothing is printed is that, on the first iteration, `files` is empty, so `for a in files` is not entered. Then on the following iterations (where `root` is A, B and C respectively), `subdirs` is empty, so `for f in subdirs` is not entered.

### Solution

In fact you can ignore `subdirs` entirely. Instead walk the current dir, and join `src`/`dst` + `root` + `a`:

```
import os

src = r'c:\data\AM\Desktop\Source'
dst = r'c:\data\AM\Desktop\Destination'

os.chdir(src)

for root, subdirs, files in os.walk('.'):
    src_dir = os.path.join(src, root)
    dst_dir = os.path.join(dst, root)

    for a in files:
        src_file = os.path.join(src_dir, a)
        dst_file = os.path.join(dst_dir, a)
        print(src_file)
        print(dst_file)
```

The output should have an extra dot directory between `src`/`dst` and `root`. If anyone could tell me how to get rid of it, I'm all ears.

Comment: Well firsts of  all thank you I think your code did (almost) exactly what I wanted. I just noticed that the 'print(dst_file)' gives the exact same output as print(src_file). which is: c:\data\AM\Desktop\Source\A\A.txt  The (dst_file) should have Destination at the end of the path not Source.. How can I change that because when I want to rewite the files this will cause me problems. The files need to be re-written in the destination A,B and C folders..

Comment: @AK28 Ah whoops, I confused myself. Changing working directories is actually needed (or at least it's the easiest solution). I updated it.

Comment: Pffff, you're good. The code did exactly what I wanted. Now 2 more things, just what does the ('.') mean? And would this also be possible if I add a new 3th folder  next to Source and Destination. Much appreciated!

Comment: @AK28 The dot means "current directory", and when it's in a path like `Source\.\A`, it's ignored. If you added another destination folder then yes, otherwise it depends what you mean.

Comment: Thank you wjandrea.